# h5 model ope error OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, model, h5py

I have a project which I cloned from GitHub for chatbot. It has a h5 model file as emoji_model.h5 and it contains

`version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:fa1b66494eb29a0ae5c1c28b44c15bb1f8ce8c3e3dae38f21b8aac1f43e26ee2
size 208336040`

when I run `python3 application.py` I get the below error

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 78, in <module>
    get_model()
  File "application.py", line 19, in get_model
    model = load_model('emoji_model.h5')
  File "/Users/shamilasallay/Documents/MSC/year2/semester2/MCS3204-Project/examples/Emojify-ML-Flask-App-master/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras
/engine/saving.py", line 417, in load_model
    f = h5dict(filepath, 'r')
  File "/Users/shamilasallay/Documents/MSC/year2/semester2/MCS3204-Project/examples/Emojify-ML-Flask-App-master/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras
/utils/io_utils.py", line 186, in __init__
    self.data = h5py.File(path, mode=mode)
  File "/Users/shamilasallay/Documents/MSC/year2/semester2/MCS3204-Project/examples/Emojify-ML-Flask-App-master/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/
_hl/files.py", line 408, in __init__
    swmr=swmr)
  File "/Users/shamilasallay/Documents/MSC/year2/semester2/MCS3204-Project/examples/Emojify-ML-Flask-App-master/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/
_hl/files.py", line 173, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 88, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

I have no idea if I should download h5 data from somewhere. I can't proceed without resolving this error. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I think it is finding `'emoji_model.h5'`, but can't read it as a HDF5.  Despite the name it isn't that format, or there's some version incompatibility.  If you have some HDF5 utilities in the OS, such as `h5dump`,it might be worth seeing if they can read the file.

Answer (score 0):

A web search for `emoji_model.h5` finds 2 websites that mention your `application.py` source and this .h5 file. Links at the end.
I downloaded `emoji_model.h5` from the github site, and tried to open with some HDF5 utilites (`h5dump` and `HDFView`). Both failed. I don't think this is a valid HDF5 file (or if it is, it's corrupt).

Links:
 - [EMOJIFY ML Web App](https://towardsdatascience.com/emojify-machine-learning-web-app-using-flask-containerization-deployment-on-aws-14a9bdb75535)
 - [Related GitHub site](https://github.com/SRIRAM777/Emojify-ML-Flask-App)